# Can't use my 9.0.1 iPhone with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

My Macbook and my iPhone are updated to the OS X 10.11 Capitan and iOS 9.0.1, but when I try to use my iPhone as a running device with Xcode, it tells me I can't use it because of the version of them.

I can't upgrade Xcode (6.1). On the App Store, it tells me I'm on the latest version.

Comment: did you update your phone to iOS 9

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm on 9.0.2 (13A452)

Comment: you should delete the previous version of Xcode maybe

Comment: Will try this. I hope it will allow me to install the xCode 7 version.

Answer (score 2):

You need upgrade your xCode (6.1) to  [Xcode 7.0.1](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) and above to support iOS 9.0.1. and upgrade your [Mac OS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-yosemite/id1018109117) also Version no : 10.11

Comment: When I check the App Store, it says that I'm already on xCode 7. But in Xcode -> About it -> 6.1

Comment: appstore shows the updated version including beta version , but  Xcode -> About it -> 6.1 --> this is correct, you need to upgrade your xcode and OS also , it solve your issue

Comment: But I can't upgrade it. Maybe I missed it ? Where can I find the latest version ?

Comment: My Mac OS is already on 10.11. I'm trying to update xCode to 7.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Install xcode 7.0 it will fix your issue.

Comment: Ok it works fine, but I think I need a dev account to test my app on my iPhone. I can use emulator only...

Comment: Yes you are right, developer/enterprise account is must to test your application in device.

Comment: but I can export my app to test it on my phone right ?